# az containerapp create with --image argument along with --yaml argument

Tags: azure, containers, azure-container-apps

I am using this to create a azure container app

```
az containerapp create -n sample -g my-container-app-env --image sampleapi-docker-build.domainname/sample-dotnet:2.0.2989 --yaml ./configuration.yml
```

In my configuration.yml file

```
template:
containers:
  - name: sample-dotnet
    #image: sampleapi-docker-verify.domain/sample-dotnet:2.0.2989
    resources:
      cpu: 0.25
      memory: .5Gi
```

The image tag is commented out, I am trying to pass it as an argument to the create command. This is the error

```
(ContainerAppImageRequired) Container with name 'sample-dotnet' must have an 'Image' property specified.
```

How do I supply some arguments in create command and others in the yaml configuration file??

Answer (score -1):

> > The image tag is commented out, I am trying to pass it as an argument
> > to the create command. This is the error
>
> ````
> (ContainerAppImageRequired) Container with name 'sample-dotnet' must have an '```
> 'Image' property specified
> ````

If you pass the configuration using `yaml` while you creating container app using `Az Cli`  Path to a `.yaml` file with the configuration of a container app and remaining all other parameters will be ignored. check the [MS Doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/container-apps/azure-resource-manager-api-spec#examples.) for your reference.

To resolve the issue, kindly pass the all configuration except **container app** name and **resource group** name

**Azure Cli Command to create container app.**

```
az containerapp create -n mywebapp -g Sri --yaml "C:\Users\user\configuration.yml"
```

**Configuration.yml**

```yaml
    location: "West US 2"
    type: Microsoft.App/containerApps
    properties:
      managedEnvironmentId: /subscriptions/7195d375-7af2-43f1-bd66-12e77ac05818/resourceGroups/Sri/providers/Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments/managedEnvironment-Sri-b57d
      configuration:
        secrets:
          - name: myregistrypassword
            value: xxxxxxxxxxKPzkmJIXiTn/MCKkvNAL+ACRCDlME+
        registries:
          - passwordSecretRef: myregistrypassword
            server: vnfhfhf.azurecr.io
            username: venkattest
      template:
        containers:
          - image: venkattest.fnfnf .io/mywebapp:v1
            name: mywebapp
```

**Output:**

[image]

Once I ran the above commands, the container app is successfully created in the portal as shown below.

[image]

Refer [Create a container app using a YAML configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp?view=azure-cli-latest&preserve-view=true#az-containerapp-create) and check [example YAML configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/container-apps/azure-resource-manager-api-spec?tabs=yaml#container-app-examples)